# Alarm with toggle buttons as days to set alarm

Tags: android, alarm, togglebutton, repeatingalarm

I have a button, textview and 7 toggle buttons. Every toggle button is a day of the week.

I got the alarm working when you tap the button, timePickerDialog opens and after choosing time, it shows the time in the textview and sets the alarm at that time.

But now I would be able to set that, when 3 of the toggle buttons are on for example (for example Monday, Tuesday and Sunday), the alarm will set on those days.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a separate repeating alarm for each activated day. See the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) on how to set a repeating alarm.